# Closing exe and running from memory

Tags: c++, python

Since exe is an archive, I want my program to be able to save stuff to it's own exe file. Unfortunately, Windows keeps the file open while it's running. I'd like to find a way in Python and/or C++ to force the program to run from memory and have the file close.

Comment: I'm thinking you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what both an exe and an archive really are.

Comment: Archive - "The place where such documents or records are kept"
Open one with 7zip

Comment: So you can store files in an exe, which I would like to do.

Comment: A program is _always_ run from memory.

Comment: @Hawkwing: Well, you can't, at least not dynamically like you want to. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, but the file stays open. I want to close the exe file.

Comment: On modern Windows versions (Vista+), you can't write to your EXE anyway. The whole \Program Files\ directory is protected.

Answer (score 3):

You can't save data to a program's own code without resorting to some dangerous, and frankly, pointless, hacks. So the short answer is "you can't do this." And why would you ever want to?

An EXE is not an "archive." It's a set of machine code to be executed, meant to be read-only. It may contain data, but that data is for use by the program in specific places and the program knows how to refer to those places.

Comment: I've always thought it would be nifty if I could store data in the area where string literals are kept, instead of keeping an .ini file floating around.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well, sorry to rain on your parade, but it ain't happening. Why don't you just use a nice Settings file like those .NET offers?

Comment: Try experimenting with exe's and Python's zipfile module, you can use them as archives.

Comment: @Hawkwing: No, you can't. They can have an archive inside them which they then read and extract. It is not writable; to create such an archive, a new program must be modified and/or compiled.

Comment: Run this Python code
import zipfile

z=zipfile.ZipFile('filepath/test.exe','a')
z.write(z.write('filepath/test.txt','test.txt')
z.close()

then open the exe with 7zip.
I'm absolutely positive that it's possible, it's just looking like it's not the most feasible thing to do.

Comment: @Hawkwing This is ugly. It append zip data to the end of the executable file. You could use anything other than ZipFile there.

Answer (score 1):

While you are correct, that you can have embedded resources (like images, other files, etc) in an EXE (executable file) - these are placed there at compile time and the PE file is specially structured to allow this.  However, it would be a very *bad idea* to try and do this at run time.  I'm not saying it is impossible, but there are far, far better ways of doing *whatever it is* you're trying to do.